# Different strategies of memoization lead to vastly different runtime

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I was trying to solve leetcode problem 416 - https://leetcode.com/problems/partition-equal-subset-sum/description/

> Given a non-empty array nums containing only positive integers, find if the array can be partitioned into two subsets such that the sum of elements in both subsets is equal.

I encountered some interesting results trying to optimize my solution. I tried to optimize my recursive solution to avoid the dreaded "time limit exceeded" like so:

```
class Solution:
    def canPartition(self, nums: List[int]) -> bool:
        totalSum = sum(nums) 
        if totalSum % 2 == 1:
            return False
        @cache
        def helper(index, setOne):
            if setOne < 0:
                return False
            if setOne == 0:
                return True
            for x in range(index, len(nums)):
                if helper(x +1, setOne - nums[x]):
                    return True
            return False
        return helper(0,totalSum // 2)
```

It "helped" to improve the runtime, 36 -> 74 test cases passed, but I am still getting TLE

I took a look at the accepted solutions and I have calculated my solution should have the same exact runtime, yet different thought process.

Here is the solution link - https://leetcode.com/problems/partition-equal-subset-sum/solutions/1624939/c-python-5-simple-solutions-w-explanation-optimization-from-brute-force-to-dp-to-bitmask/

and the python code which I am referring to:

```
class Solution:
    def canPartition(self, nums):
        @cache
        def subsetSum(s, i):
            if s == 0: return True
            if i >= len(nums) or s < 0: return False
            return subsetSum(s-nums[i], i+1) or subsetSum(s, i+1)
        total_sum = sum(nums)
        return total_sum & 1 == 0 and subsetSum(total_sum // 2, 0)
```

At this point the closest answer I have is there is some hidden variable I have forgotten to memoize. Would love to get some insight why my code is inefficient.

Side Note:

At first I thought that my code was inefficient ie. o(n * 2^n), but further analysis leads me to believe that it is o(2^n) as the for loop only makes a binary choice for each index (choose index or not), please correct me if I am wrong!

Edit:
I have listened to user2357112's advice, but still get TLE. I have edited the improved code above. It improved the runtime significantly, but still not accepted. I am guess this is probably an issue with the leetcode algorithm at this point.

Comment: Your nested function is still not doing the same thing; the other solution tests two paths (`s-nums[i]` and `s`), yours tests all `s-nums[x]` values from `nums[i]` up to `nums[-1]`. The `s-nums[i+1:]` values are also being tested with higher `index` values, so you have N extra recursive calls that will have the same outcome but can't reuse the cache.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: `False` outcomes are the only ones that need to be memoized, though - as soon as any call returns `True`, the whole stack of `helper` calls unwinds immediately, all returning `True`, then `canPartition` returns and `helper` is discarded.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you agree that the time complexity is the same, but it is the way I am recursively calling the function that is the issue?

if you are doubtful on the time complexity, please look at the solution to the subsets problem:

https://leetcode.com/problems/subsets/solutions/27281/a-general-approach-to-backtracking-questions-in-java-subsets-permutations-combination-sum-palindrome-partitioning/

where I got inspiration of my code. If you go through the comment chain, it is o(2^n), but the copy of the array (which is not done in the problem) is what makes it 0(n*2^n)

Comment: The other solution tests two paths: those where `num[i]` was used to find the solution, and those paths where `num[i]` was not used to find the solution. Any subset of numbers in the array that sum to exactly half the total would be a solution, so the original creates all possible subsets this way. Yours creates the same subset in multiple recursion paths.

Comment: Anyway, user2357112 has identified the problem: not exiting early when `s < 0`.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to stop recursing if you *overshoot* the target.

Unrelated: note that some of the "solutions" in that solution link don't actually work. For example "solution" 3 fails on input `[100, 125, 185, 60, 195, 25]`, because the memoization logic is broken - memoizing the index as well as the subset sum really is necessary.

Comment: That's it. The `s < 0` case has to go through the whole `for` loop before reaching the `return False`.

Comment: Thank you!

I added:

"if setOne < 0:
                return False"

to the top of the function, it still give TLE but only 2 test cases fail the time limit. 138/140 much better than 74/140 I was getting before.

i guess this is just a problem with leetcode runtime algorithms then?

Comment: @just-an-average-programmer: Martijn's initial observation still applies: you have too many recursive calls. (Honestly, for all that I'm a big fan of recursive analysis, I'm not convinced that it's helpful here. The dynamic programming solution is simple and easily optimised, and actually does not require memoising the partial sets.)

Comment: @rici, so in other words the time complexity WITHOUT memoization is the same for both solutions, but the way which I recurse does not lead to optimal caching?

Comment: @just-an-average-programmer: I don't think your code ever actually generates the same subset twice. If their code passed (did you try it?), it's not because your code (with the overshoot fix) has algorithmic problems theirs doesn't. (Also, note that some of their "solutions" are wrong - for example, "solution" 3 in the link is completely broken.)

Comment: yes, that is what I was thinking :) The why I implement DFS is such a way that caching is almost not possible because there is no repetition

Comment: @just-an-average-programmer: The caching helps a little, if the same sum comes up twice. Actually, I think I just realized where the last performance difference is coming from - say your code finds a subset with sum 10, whose last element is at index 4, and then later finds another subset with sum 10, whose last element is at index 2. Your code will consider all elements at indexes 3 and up as candidates for the next element. Their code will try indexes 3 and 4 as candidate next elements, then hit the cached `subsetSum(10, 5)` and not try any later indexes.